# Adding a .zip file to the body of an LWP::UserAgent POST request

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

I believe I have a general Perl problem, rather than an LWP::UserAgent problem... however its somewhat complex.

The task is to write a test-script that does a [SWORD](http://www.swordapp.org/docs/sword-profile-1.3.html) deposit.
I create tests by first writing code to prove the thing works, then add in the `Test::More` wrappers to make it a test.

**BACKGROUND**

A SWORD deposit is simply an http post request with a bunch of defined headers, and the content of the body being the thing to be ingested. This all works fine, I can perform the actions through CURL, and I've written scripts to do this.... but within a a larger application environment (that'll be [EPrints](http://www.eprints.org/).)

**CODE**

My problem, I believe, comes when I try to attach the contents of the file on the disk.

```
#!/home/cpan/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;
##use WWW::Mechanize;
use File::Slurp;
use MIME::Base64;

my $auth     = 'username:password';
my $domain   = 'devel.example.com';

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();

my $basedir = "./test_files";

my $package  = 'http://opendepot.org/europePMC/2.0';
my $filename = "$basedir/PMC165035.zip";
my $mime     = 'application/zip';
print "filename: $filename\n";
my $deposit_url = $domain . '/sword-app/deposit/archive';

my $file = read_file( $filename, { binmode => ':raw' } );

# Set up the SWORD deposit
my $autho = "Basic " . MIME::Base64::encode( $auth, '' );

my %headers = (
  'X-Packaging'         => $package,
  'X-No-Op'             => 'false',
  'X-Verbose'           => 'true',
  'Content-Disposition' => "filename=$filename",
  'Content-Type'        => $mime,
  'User-Agent'          => 'Broker Test Harness',
  'Authorization'       => $autho,
); 
my $r = $ua->post( $deposit_url, %headers, Content => $file );

# DEBUG TEST
write_file('foo.zip', $file);

my $ret = $r->decoded_content;
print "Content: $ret\n";
if ( $r->is_success ) { print "Deposited $package successfully" }
```

**WHAT WORKS, WHAT DOESN'T**

This code is lifted pretty much directly from working code I have - the only difference is that the working code gets the content for `$file` via an object-call within EPrints.

I know the file exists on the disk, if I do an `ls -l` on the filename printed, I can see the file, and its readable

In the code above, there is a line `write_file('foo.zip', $file);` - that writes a file which `unzip -l foo.zip` happily tells me has 3 files in it.

The line `print "Content: $ret\n";` should print an *atom* response - for me, it prints nothing.... 
The Access log reports an error 500, but there's diddly-squat in the error-log.

**The help**

What I need to know is how I get the actual contents of the .zip file into the `content` part of the LWP::UserAgent post request...

(I'm going to spend much time not trying to dig into EPrints, to track where the error-500 is coming from, and why nothing appears in the log file.... but that's probably going to be down to an issue with what's been **posted**)

Comment: There is no protocol (`http://`) at the start of `$deposit_url`

Comment: You also need `binmode => ':raw'` in your call to `write_file`

Comment: It is best to use `unzip -t foo.zip` to verify your zip file. Alternatively, if you're just copying one zip file to an other then why not use `File::Copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution lies in realizing what LWP POST is doing.

```
my $filename = "$basedir/PMC165035.zip";
my $file = read_file( $filename, { binmode => ':raw' } );
my %headers = (
  'X-Packaging'         => $package,
  'X-No-Op'             => 'false',
  'X-Verbose'           => 'true',
  'Content-Disposition' => "filename=$filename",
  'Content-Type'        => $mime,
  'User-Agent'          => 'Broker Test Harness',
  'Authorization'       => $autho,
);
```

All work by setting `$filename` to be something like `/home/services/foo/testing/test_files/PMC165035.zip`, and passing this (full) filename to the server *example.com*.

The problem is that the server is looking for a filename, not a filename-with-path... so when the service does its thing with the file by dumping the *content* into its temporary upload location, and then it looks for  `~~~temp_location/home/services/foo/testing/test_files/PMC165035.zip`, it can't find it!

The solution is to read in the file, but ensure that the filename given in the headers is just the filename, not *with-a-path*